# Symfony 3.4 : RecursiveValidator or TraceableValidator?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a problem with my service.

```
 <service id="api.api" class="ApiBundle\Service\ApiService">
        <argument type="service" id="request_stack"/>
        <argument type="service" id="validator"/>
 </service>
```

The __construct is :

```
public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack, RecursiveValidator  $validator)
{
    $this->request = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
    $this->validator = $validator;
}
```

The problem is:

- ENV_DEV, the validator must be an instance of **TraceableValidator**
- ENV_PROD, the validator must be an instance of **RecursiveValidator**

Do you know why I have this conflict ?

In ENV_DEV with RecursiveValidator, I have this error :

```
Type error: Argument 2 passed to 
ApiBundle\Service\ApiService::__construct() must be an instance of 
Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\RecursiveValidator, 
instance of Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\TraceableValidator 
given, called in 
var/cache/dev/ContainerLqjid6c/getApi_ApiService.php on line 8
```

`cache:clear` doesn't solve the problem.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You have to use an interface that both your class implements. The injection of the service may fail if you utiliser autowire, you would have to do extra steps

Comment: Is there any documentation anywhere that explains WHY TraceableValidator is used in ENV_DEV and RecursiveValidator is used in ENV_PROD??

Comment: I didn't find any documentation about it when I had the problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of hinting to an implementation, you should always (if available) hint to an interface. In this case, both [`RecursiveValidator`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Validator/RecursiveValidator.php) and [`TraceableValidator`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Validator/TraceableValidator.php) implement the [`ValidatorInterface`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Validator/ValidatorInterface.php).

So your constructor should look like this:

```
public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack, ValidatorInterface  $validator)
{
    $this->request = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
    $this->validator = $validator;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. That's work Thank you for this advice. I note this recommendation.
Thanks again.